# Setting the boolean value of aria-expanded using React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accessibility, antd

I'm currently working on accessibility in a web application using React & Ant Design's Select component. `aria-expanded` is set to `false` string.

I want to use React `useState` to toggle `aria-expanded="false"` so that the aria label in the screen reader can read back wether the dropdown is open or closed.

The idea is to take the default state and use it in the useState hook like this:

```
const [selectAria, setSelectAria] = useState('false');

            <Select
              name="someName"
              id="someID"
              onSelect={(value) => handleChangeSelect(value)}
              aria-label={
                selectAria ? 'i am closed' : 'i am open '
              }
              aria-expanded={selectAria}
            >
```

The screen reader is only able to recognize when the initial state. After I select an option, and the dropdown is closed, it does not read back the new state.

Is it possible to do this in React hooks? Is it possible to access the `aria-expanded` attribute in `useState` along with the boolean value? I haven't worked on advanced accessibility and have to stick with the antD library for this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ant Design, they have provided a bunch of `props` with very simple names to get our things done in a very friendly manner.

You can decide the initial openness/closeness of your Select element using `defaultOpen`  prop and, always one-to-one bound openness/closeness using `open` prop.

Here you want to control the open/close action in always one-to-one bound manner I guess. So your code should be like this!

```js
const [selectAria, setSelectAria] = useState(false);

    <Select
      name="someName"
      id="someID"
      onSelect={(value) => handleChangeSelect(value)}
      open={selectArea}
    >
```

*Note: Removed your `aria-label` attribute as well. Refer official AntD documentation for a suitable prop [API - Select Component](https://ant.design/components/select/#API)!

**Note: If you use this `open` prop I mentioned above, it may never allow you to close the panel until your `selectAria` variable is `true`. So you have to carefully handle that situation as well!

***Note: This answer is referred to Ant Design version 4.7.3. Select the correct version of documentation before you refer!

Comment: sorry for the late update. I was very busy on the project & forgot to update my response.

Comment: No worries. Glad to help you!